# Using BERT for classification given character length or number of words in a sentence

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

I have a dataset of titles, their descriptions and 0 or 1s that correspond to whether the description is valid or not. I want to be able to classify whether they are valid or not based on BERT alongside the character/word count of the description. How would I do so?

Comment: way too broad. Please start using BERT, and narrow the problem down. The question is not answerable for now.

Answer (score 1):

This question is little broad, but you can start off as follows:

You can probably use `Cola` processor of bert, which is a suitable processor for Binary Classification problem.

You can consider the Titles as the ID,as it should not influence the training, and it can uniquely identify the description.

Create the TSV files as per the required problem, you can use Glue data for Cola task to see how the data has to be formatted for bert.

Generally training and Dev set has 4 columns, namely, `id`, `class`, `segment ID`, `text data`, and test set has only 2 columns `id` and `text data`.

You can perform the fine-tuning once you get the data in the required format. You can use the `run_classifier.py` script to do the finetuning. The authors have documented the way to use the mentioned script for fine-tuning [here](https://github.com/google-research/bert)